# MYSQLi Query not inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My MYSQLi query is not inserting properly into the database and I am not sure where the syntax error is. Please help!

```
$name     = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$mail     = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
$comment  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$postid   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['postid']);

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `comment` (name, mail, comment, post_id) VALUES ({$name}, {$mail}, {$comment}, {$postid})");
```

Comment: your code is fine , you didnt come to this code, show your full code

Comment: If you print `mysqli_error($con)` when the query fails, you might get a clue as to the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to surruound with quotes your strings in your query, only integer field can be inserted without quotes

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `comment` (name, mail, comment, post_id) VALUES ('$name', '$mail', '$comment', '$postid')");
```

Since you are already using `mysqli` I would rather use [**prepared statements**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mysqli/info) instead of sanitize your variables and then insert in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `comment` (name, mail, comment, post_id) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$mail."', '".$comment."', '".$postid."')");
```

It should work now..

Comment: you cant surround table name with quotes

Comment: :o really? I am really sorry, usually I put quotes, but if it's wrong, thank you man, now I will use the others characters. But, if I use quotes instead of the others characters, there are some security issues?